# Using TransactionScope to update tables located on geographically-separated servers (not linked)

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactionscope

I am in need of writing a process that needs to update 2 identical tables located in 2 different databases on servers that are geographically separated.

We can't add one of the servers as a linked server due to some security considerations.

The requirement is also that if either of the process fails, both transactions should be rolled back. It's all or nothing. After [reading the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) on MSDN regarding `TransactionScope` it appears as though this class will take care of business for you but there are some fuzzy areas on the documentation that I am hoping someone with experience using this approach can clarify for me:

1. The documentation says that you can connect to 2 different databases or even a 3rd party RDBMS but it doesn't specify whether the database servers must be "linked"
2. Assuming they don't need to be linked, can you explain, roughly, how does the TransactionScope handles exceptions and manages to roll back when an error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servers should not be linked. They even can be completely different (we use `TransactionScope` for distributed transactions between MS SQL and IBM Websphere MQ). Actually it uses MSDTC service that acts as transaction coordinator for [two phase commit transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).

Though it sounds very powerful and promising, making it work may be tricky. You need to have MSTDC service up and running on all participating servers, its ports should be open in firewall and several security options should be properly configured.

The following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924%28v=bts.20%29.aspx) may be helpful